# Executing a top-level from a function on another file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Good afternoon, I've been here for a couple of hours puzzled with this wall.

I'm trying to execute a top-level from another file, it works, but I've to click the button twice.

```
# main.py
print("main.py\n")

from tkinter import * 
from windowMaker import *

root = Tk()

# Gets window's Width and Height values.
windowWidth = root.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = root.winfo_reqheight()
#print("Width:",windowWidth,"Height:",windowHeight)

# Gets window's halves (Width and Height from the screen and window)
positionRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
positionDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)

# Puts the window in the center of the user's screen.
root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))

window = Button(root, text="Create", command=createWindow)
window.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky="we")

window = Button(root, text="Read", command=readWindow)
window.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky="we")

window = Button(root, text="Update", command=updateWindow)
window.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky="we")

window = Button(root, text="Delete", command=deleteWindow)
window.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky="we")

mainloop()
```

Executing the main.py

> > main.py
> >
> > windowMaker.py

*clicks the "Create" Button*

> > f: createWindow
> >
> > main.py

*clicks it again*

> > f: createWindow

*opens the top-level*

```
# windowMaker.py
print("windowMaker.py\n")

from tkinter import * 


def createWindow():
    print("f: createWindow")
    from main import root
    window = Toplevel(root)

    pass

def readWindow():
    print("f: readWindow")
    from main import root
    window = Toplevel(root)

    pass

def updateWindow():
    print("f: updateWindow")
    from main import root
    window = Toplevel(root)

    pass

def deleteWindow():
    print("f: deleteeWindow")
    from main import root
    window = Toplevel(root)

    pass
```

If I don't import * from tkinter it doesn't work 'cause doesn't recognises anything from tkinter, If I import * from tkinter  inside of the create Functions it will give an error cause it's already imported in the main file.

I just wanted to

*press the button*
*opens the window at once not double tap*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. By running main.py you create a `root` window.
2. In windowMaker.py you have this line `from main import root` in your functions, upon your first click, this line invokes the main.py file and creates another `root` window, then your second click goes to the line below the `from main import root`, which creates your `toplevel`. This is because your second click is done on the second window generated after the first click. You do not notice this because the second window is positioned right over the first window.
3. By having `from main import root` in all your windowMaker.py functions, you are violating a basic tenet of programming(Do Not Repeat Yourself).
   You really do not need to `import root` to windowMaker.py, as you have already imported windowMaker.py into main.py, hence, all windowMaker.py functions can receive their parameters from main.py

Hence, main.py becomes:

```
# main.py
print("main.py\n")

from tkinter import * 
from windowMaker import *

root = Tk()

# Gets window's Width and Height values.
windowWidth = root.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = root.winfo_reqheight()
#print("Width:",windowWidth,"Height:",windowHeight)

# Gets window's halves (Width and Height from the screen and window)
positionRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
positionDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)

# Puts the window in the center of the user's screen.
root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))

window = Button(root, text="Create", command=lambda :createWindow(root))
window.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky="we")

window = Button(root, text="Read", command=lambda :readWindow(root))
window.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky="we")

window = Button(root, text="Update", command=lambda :updateWindow(root))
window.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky="we")

window = Button(root, text="Delete", command=lambda :deleteWindow(root))
window.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky="we")

mainloop()
```

And windowMaker.py becomes:

```
# windowMaker.py
print("windowMaker.py\n")

from tkinter import * 
#from main import root

def createWindow(root):
    print("f: createWindow")
    #from main import root
    window = Toplevel(root)

    pass

def readWindow(root):
    print("f: readWindow")
    #from main import root
    window = Toplevel(root)

    pass

def updateWindow(root):
    print("f: updateWindow")
    #from main import root
    window = Toplevel(root)

    pass

def deleteWindow(root):
    print("f: deleteeWindow")
    #from main import root
    window = Toplevel(root)

    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I know to avoid repeating code. But I was testing code and the last code I had that worked (semi-intended) was the one I left in this post. I'm still trying to figure out how does lambda [slice] function(root), OOP it's another story to me :v